# Why am I getting "Unexpected value 'with'" in my GitHub actions file?

Tags: github, github-actions

```
name : Upload website to S3

on:
    push:
        branches:
        - main

jobs:
    deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@master
        - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
        with:
            args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
        env:
            AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
            AWS_REGION: 'us-west-2'
            SOURCE_DIR: 'website'
```

My code has the subsequent line, but I'm still getting an error in my code. The line "with:" seems to have an error and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Check https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/. Might be helpful to lint your workflows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole `with:` and `env:` block must be indented 2 more spaces so that they align with the word uses.

```
jobs:
    deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
        - uses: actions/checkout@master
        - uses: jakejarvis/s3-sync-action@master
          with:
            args: --acl public-read --follow-symlinks --delete
          env:
            AWS_S3_BUCKET: ${{ secrets.AWS_S3_BUCKET }}
            AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
            AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
            AWS_REGION: 'us-west-2'
            SOURCE_DIR: 'website'
```